# Thinkster.io MEAN Stack tutorial: An empty "post" displays on the index page. Why is this, and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I am currently working through Thinkster.io's MEAN Stack tutorial.

I am on the part where the node.js backend wires up with the Angularjs front end. I have data persistence for users to add posts, as well as upvote posts.

However, an empty data post consistently appears as seen in the link below:

Landing page of my MEAN Stack App:

[image]

As you can see, below the post "World" there is a blank space with a "thumbs-up" icon and a link to make a comment. If I try to upvote this ghost post I receive the following error in the console:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/undefined/upvote Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Clearly, this blank space is undefined.

When I use the following curl command, `curl http://localhost:3000/posts` I see that my database contains the following array of objects:

> [{"_id":"5850ad61c2ed2798f3d353c1","title":"Hello","link":"","__v":0,"comments":
>   [],"upvotes":0},{"_id":"5850ad69c2ed2798f3d353c2","title":"Test","link":"","__v":0,"comments":[],"upvotes":0},{"_id":"5850ad6cc2ed2798f3d353c3","title":"World","link":"","__v":0,"comments":[],"upvotes":0}]

Obviously, that undefined object is not there. I have tried dropping the database in MongoDB, but that has not helped either.

In my angular code below, you can see where I have console logged all posts being retrieved from the backend in my post factory's o.getAll function:

```
  o.getAll = function() {
    // queries the '/posts' route
    return $http.get('/posts').success(function(data){
      // Creates a deep copy of the returned data (ensures $scope.posts in MainCtrl is updated)
      angular.copy(data, o.posts);
      console.log(o.posts);
    });
  };
```

This yields the following in the console:

[image]

The console log returns an array of 4 objects with the last being "undefined".

I have no idea why this is happening and no clue of how to get rid of it. I have searched all over Stack Overflow as well as other resources found through google and surprisingly I have found very little on this issue. Perhaps I could phrase my question better?

Please see the rest of my code below for reference:

newsly/models/Comments.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  body: String,
  author: String,
  upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
  post: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post'}
});

mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

newsly/models/Posts.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  link: String,
  upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
  comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});

// method that adds upvote to count and saves it
PostSchema.methods.upvote = function(cb) {
  this.upvotes += 1;
  this.save(cb);
};

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

newsly/public/javascripts/angularApp.js

```
// Defines the app as an angular module. Includes ui-router as a dependency.
var app = angular.module('newsly', ['ui.router']);

//factory for posts
app.factory('posts', ['$http', function($http){
  var o = {
    posts: []
  };
  // Retrieves post from backend
  o.getAll = function() {
    // queries the '/posts' route
    return $http.get('/posts').success(function(data){
      // Creates a deep copy of the returned data (ensures $scope.posts in MainCtrl is updated)
      angular.copy(data, o.posts);
      console.log(o.posts);
    });
  };
  // method for creating new posts
  o.create = function(post) {
    // binds function that will be executed when the request returns
    return $http.post('/posts', post).success(function(data){
      o.posts.push(data);
    });
  };
  o.upvote = function(post) {
    return $http.put('/posts/' + post._id + '/upvote').success(function(data){
      post.upvotes += 1;
    });
  };
  return o;
}]);
// Main conterller referenced in the <body> tag.
app.controller('MainCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  // injects 'posts' service in the Main controller
  'posts',
  function($scope, posts){
    // Binds the posts array in the factory to the $scope.posts variable
    $scope.posts = posts.posts;
    // addPost function
    $scope.addPost = function(){
      // Stops a user from submitting a blank title
      if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
      // saves posts to the server, persistent data
      posts.create({
        title: $scope.title,
        link: $scope.link,
      });
      $scope.title = '';
      $scope.link = '';
    }
    // Pushes the new post to the $scope.post array
    $scope.posts.push({
      title: $scope.title,
      link: $scope.link,
      upvotes: 0,
      comments: []
    });
    $scope.title = '';
    $scope.link = '';
    // incrementUpvotes function
    $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post){
      posts.upvote(post);
    }
  }]);

  app.controller('PostsCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$stateParams',
    'posts',
    function($scope, $stateParams, posts){
      // Grabs the appropriate post from the posts factory using the id from $stateParams.
      $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];
      $scope.addComment = function(){
        if($scope.body === '') {return; }
        $scope.post.comments.push({
          body: $scope.body,
          author: 'user',
          upvotes: 0
        });
        $scope.body = '';
      };
      $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(comment){
        comment.upvotes += 1;
      };
    }]);

    // Configures home state using $stateProvider
    app.config([
      '$stateProvider',
      '$urlRouterProvider',
      function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url:'/home',
          templateUrl: '/home.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl',
          // property of ui-router that ensures posts are loaded
          resolve: {
            postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
              return posts.getAll();
            }]
          }
        })
        // Posts state: individual posts and their comments
        .state('posts', {
          // {id} is a route parameter, made available in the controller
          url: '/posts/{id}',
          templateUrl: '/posts.html',
          controller: 'PostsCtrl'
        });

        // Redirects unspecified routes
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
      }]);
```

newsly/routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');

// GET Request
router.get('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
  Post.find(function(err, posts){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(posts);
  });
});

// POST route for creating posts
router.post('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
  var post = new Post(req.body);

  post.save(function(err, post) {
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(post);
  });
});

// route for automatically preloading post objects ****uses Expressjs' param() function****
router.param('post', function(req, res, next, id) {
  var query = Post.findById(id);
  // Use's mongoose's query interface which provides a more flexible way of interacting with the database.
  query.exec(function (err, post) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!post) { return next(new Error('can\'t find post')); }

    req.post = post;
    return next();
  });
});

// Route for returning a single post
router.get('/posts/:post', function(req, res, next) {
  // populate function automatically loads all comments associated with a post
  req.post.populate('comments', function(err, post){
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.json(post);
  });
});

// route for adding upvotes
router.put('/posts/:post/upvote', function(req, res, next) {
  req.post.upvote(function(err, post){
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.json(post);
  });
});

//route for comments, attached to a certain post via post ID
router.post('/posts/:post/comments', function(req, res, next) {
  var comment = new Comment(req.body);
  comment.post = req.post;

  comment.save(function(err, comment){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    req.post.comments.push(comment);
    req.post.save(function(err, post) {
      if(err){ return next(err); }

      res.json(comment);
    });
  });
});

//route to upvote comments
router.put('posts/:post/comments/:comment/upvote', function(req, res, next){
  req.comment.upvote(function(err, comment){
    if (err) {return next(err); }

    res.json(post);
  });
});

router.param('comment', function(req, res, next, id) {
  var query = Post.findById(id);
  // Use's mongoose's query interface which provides a more flexible way of interacting with the database.
  query.exec(function (err, comment) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!comment) { return next(new Error('can\'t find comment')); }

    req.comment = comment;
    return next();
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

newsly/views/index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Newsly</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">

  <!-- Angular -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
  <!-- ui-router library -->
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/angularApp.js"></script>
  <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up { cursor:pointer } </style>
</head>

<!-- Main controller. Containes addPost and incrementUpvotes functions -->
<body ng-app="newsly">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <!-- Whenever ui-router detects a route change, it places the new states template here and intializes that state's controller -->
      <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- In-line templates for states. -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
    <div class='page-header'>
      <h1>Newsly</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- Shows all posts ordered by upvotes. -->
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: '-upvotes'">
      <!-- When a user clicks thumbs-up the post's upvote will increment by 1 -->
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
      {{post.upvotes}}
      <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
        <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
          {{post.title}}
        </a>
        <!-- If a user does not submit a link, only the title will be shown. -->
        <span ng-hide="post.link">
          {{post.title}}
        </span>
        <span>
          <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>

    <!-- Form to add Posts -->
    <form ng-submit="addPost()" style="margin-top:30px;">
      <h3>Add a new post</h3>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Link" ng-model="link">
      </div>
      <!-- Users can either press "enter" or click the "Post" button -->
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </form>
  </script>

  <!-- Posts template -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h3>
        <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
          {{post.title}}
        </a>
        <span ng-hide="post.link">
          {{post.title}}
        </span>
      </h3>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments | orderBy: '-upvotes'">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="incrementUpvotes(comment)"></span>
      {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
      <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
        {{comment.body}}
      </span>
    </div>

    <form ng-submit="addComment()" style="margin-top:30px;">
      <h3>Add a new comment</h3>

      <div class="form group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" ng-model="body">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </form>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

newsly/app.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./models/Posts');
require('./models/Comments');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news');



var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
// app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Any insight into this mystery would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer!

I spoke to a friend who suggested the issue was actually in `app.controller('MainCtrl', [`

Sure enough, I closed `$scope.addPost = function()` too early, specifically before `$scope.post.push.`

Here is my new MainCtrl:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  // injects 'posts' service in the Main controller
  'posts',
  function($scope, posts){
    // Binds the posts array in the factory to the $scope.posts variable
    $scope.posts = posts.posts;
    // addPost function
    $scope.addPost = function(){
      // Stops a user from submitting a blank title
      if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
      // saves posts to the server, persistent data
      posts.create({
        title: $scope.title,
        link: $scope.link,
      });
      $scope.title = '';
      $scope.link = '';
      // Pushes the new post to the $scope.post array
      $scope.posts.push({
        title: $scope.title,
        link: $scope.link,
        upvotes: 0,
        comments: []
      });
      $scope.title = '';
      $scope.link = '';
    } //bracket placed here instead of before $scope.posts.push
    // incrementUpvotes function
    $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post){
      posts.upvote(post);
    }
  }]);
```

The ghost post is now gone!